# Laravel - Automatically changing the results if null is returned

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im wondering if I could get some advice.

In my blade template, i have the following;

```
<a href="#">{{ $gallery->creator->name }}</a>
```

My controller looks like this;

```
public function show(Gallery $gallery)
{
    return view('galleries.show', compact('gallery'));
}
```

The next bit is where im having some trouble, In my model i have the following relationship

```
public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Some of the galleries have a null user_id value as they are not logged in when posted.

Is there a way that I can set the $gallery->creator->name to 'Anonymous' if the user_id is null, but if there is a value, use whats already there? Any help making a mutator would be awesome

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: you can use a mutator for this, take a look here: [laravel mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

Comment: @user3681740 Hey, this looks like a good idea ... Is there any chance you could give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed this issue in my case.

Inside the `Gallery` model, where you have this relationship defined:

```
public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Add this accessor:

```
public function getCreatorNameAttribute()
{
    if ($this->creator) {
        return $this->creator->name;
    }
    return "Anonymous"; // any default value you want to return here.
}
```

And how to use it blade template:

```
<a href="#">{{ $gallery->creatorName }}</a>
```

Comment: Perfect ... Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">{{ $gallery->creator ? $gallery->creator->name : 'Anonymous' }}</a>
```